# When a table is locked but SHOW PROCESSLIST shows nothing

Tags: innodb, mariadb, locking

We had some slowness in our application. When I checked I figure out that one particular table was locked so all transactions were rejected by `Lock wait timeout exceeded`. When I did `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` I was expecting to see  some processes with `Waiting for table level lock` state but it shows nothing !? only some queries INSERT/UPDATE on the same table taking exactly 120 seconds before time-out and others processes on sleeping state (see picture):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason in my case was that one transaction is making a read-lock on a particular table leading to a "`Lock wait timeout exceeded`" because its not committed. So all other transactions are waiting to that particular tranx to do commit.

Now, why `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` show nothing ? In fact, it does.
you'll find it (the process) with a "Sleep" state and with no query shown in the info column like if it's just a regular connection to the database.

Let's check my example in the image :[image]

In Blue, those are some very simple queries blocked (taking 120 second before a time-out) and the red one is the "ghost" or non-committed transaction.

To see those kind of transactions execute :

```
SELECT TRX_ID, TRX_REQUESTED_LOCK_ID, TRX_MYSQL_THREAD_ID, TRX_QUERY
FROM INNODB_TRX
```

And you may kill the process `kill <id>;` in which `TRX_QUERY` is null to free other transactions. In my case, `KILL 33267342;`

Make sure to check the non-committed transaction to see if a `commit;` or a `Rollback` clause is missing in order to ovoid such issues.

Comment: Sounds like a `BEGIN` (or autocommit=0) started a transaction that has not been `COMMITted` yet.  The Processlist would show `Sleep` if no queries are running.

Comment: In old MySQL versions (5.7) the InnoDB query is not valid. Table 'INNODB_TRX' doesn't exist.