# MySQL Workbench shows running query but query not in process list

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am having an issue where the same query sometimes completes in 600 seconds or less, but sometimes lags for multiple hours. MySQL Workbench shows the query as 'Running...', and initially I can see the query in the processlist. But after a significant amount of time after the query should have already returned results, I check the processlist and the query is no longer executing--yet Workbench still shows that it is running. What is happening to the query and why doesn't Workbench immediately give me an error code?

Sometimes if I wait a sufficiently long time to trigger a timeout I do get the 2013 error.

I am using a MacBook Pro running Big Sur connecting to a remote MySQL server through a VPN.

Could this be explained by poor network connectivity?

Comment: you should see which lock are present, which could hinder the query to finish.

Comment: you could eliminate the VPN/remote access as an issue by connecting to a machine on the remote network using RDP (or ssh, or some other kind of shell) then running the query from there.  You want to make it so that if you get a network or VPN disconnect, that won't stop the query from running.  Also, why does the query take *soooo long* under "normal" circumstances.  10 minutes is for ever.

Comment: @MaxVernon The server is an Amazon RDS and I think I will need to reach out to my DB admin to request SSH access--but I am hesitant to do this. As for the amount of time it takes, it probably has something to do with me not writing very efficient queries and the amount of data being queried. The table is over a billion rows and just to count the 1.3 million rows that I'm interested in takes 200 sec. But yes, I agree that 10min is way too long and it makes it impossible for me to use those queries in production.

Comment: Let's work on speeding up the query.  Show us the query; `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen when a transaction is not committed or even roll-backed.
I had similar issues regarding incomplete queries in here [when-a-table-is-locked-but-show-processlist-shows-nothing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/279194/89077).

Hope that help you.